# Python\ csv.writer deletes previous data instead of adding new to the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner with python so you can think that am i asking a stupid question, but i really can't understand why mine function is removing previous data in csvfile instead of adding new in to this file. That's how it looks like:

```
def writein():
    with open('employee data.csv', 'w') as employeeData:
        writeby = csv.writer(employeeData, delimiter = ',')
        writeNEN = input('Add name of new emp: \n')
        writeNESN = input('Add surname of new emp: \n')
        writeNEP = input('Add position of new emp: \n')
        writeNEBD = input('Add date of birth of new emp: \n')
        writeby.writerow([writeNEN, writeNESN, writeNEP, writeNEBD])
```

Have you guys any idea how to make program adding new data instead of replacing it?

Answer (score 3):

When you open a file in write-mode (i.e. `open('file.txt', 'w')`), the contents are cleared before things are added. The fix to your problem would be to open the csv file in append-mode:

```
def writein():
    with open('employee data.csv', 'a') as employeeData:
                             #      ^
                             # a for append
```

Comment: Thanks, for a strange reason there is nothing about append here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html

Comment: I think you'll find [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code
`with open('employee data.csv', 'a')`

parameter 'a' instructs to append.